# The U-Box-It store carries boxes in four sizes. The tables below show the four sizes of storage boxes the store sells and the revenues ...

Tags: linear-algebra

The U-Box-It store carries boxes in four sizes. The tables below show the four sizes of storage boxes the store sells and the revenues earned in the summer quarter.  For how much did each type of box sell?

[image]

I put the equations

12A + 35B + 20C + 5D = 425.25

18A + 42B + 33C + 21D = 732

20A + 28B + 24C + 10D = 500

In matrix and did rref(A) on my calculator, I got the equations

A - 55/54D = -559/108

B - 131/189D = -1009/756

C - 56/27D = 721/27

and now I am stuck and do not know how to solve for the equations in order to get a value for each of the letters A, B, C, D. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's no additional information?  It seems you only have three equations in four unknowns.

Comment: @BrianTung I am not sure if I am solving incorrectly then but this is as far as I got and the only information I was provided.

Comment: Let $a = 100A, b = 100B, c = 100C, d = 100D$. Prices in the United States are generally a whole number of cents (except for gasoline). Thus $a,b,c,d$ should all be integer. This is not just a linear algebra problem. It is also an elementary number theory problem.